# Convert string with enter keys in it to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am a newbie in javascript and UI side of programming. I have a string as follows;

```
"List↵US0023↵BZ22BK↵BYYXJY↵BYXJF6↵BWFD05↵"
```

If you see, there is a enter key after each value. I want to remove the first word. i.e. 'List' and then put the remaining in an array. Something like this below.

```
[US0023,BZ22BK,BYYXJY,BYXJF6,BWFD05]
```

Can someone suggest me how i can achieve this please

Answer (score 2):

```
"List↵US0023↵BZ22BK↵BYYXJY↵BYXJF6↵BWFD05↵".split('↵').slice(1).join(',')
```

This basically splits your string into an array, splitting with the ↵, and then uses slice 1 to remove first element, and then rejoin's using ','..

Comment: I am not able to split it for '↵'. it still shows '↵' in the string

Comment: .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); THIS WORKED

Answer (score 0):

```
array = "List↵US0023↵BZ22BK↵BYYXJY↵BYXJF6↵BWFD05↵".split("↵")

console.log(array)
/* ["List", "US0023", "BZ22BK", "BYYXJY", "BYXJF6", "BWFD05"] */

array.splice(0, 1)

console.log(array)
/* ["US0023", "BZ22BK", "BYYXJY", "BYXJF6", "BWFD05"] */
```